# Regex to allow some special character with unicodes

Tags: c#, regex

I want to allow some special characters like `(,),\,_,.,` etc
and emojis is denoted by [\u0000-\u007F]+

Valid names are

```
"❤️\U0001f923\U0001f923"
"12333❤️\U0001f923\U0001f923.txt"
"123()-213❤️\U0001f923\U0001f923.txt"
```

Invalid specialcharacters should be  replaced with ""

```
"123^&*()!@#$❤️\U0001f923\U0001f923" should be
"123()❤️\U0001f923\U0001f923"
```

This regex does it for some special characters

```
string filename = "12%&^%^&% \U0001f973\U0001f973.xlsx"
string output = Regex.Replace(filename, @"[^\w\s\.\\[\]()|_-]+", "");
prints "12 .xlsx"
```

For unicode characters (like emojis)

```
string output = Regex.Replace(filename, @"[\u0000-\u007F]+", "");
prints"\U0001f973\U0001f973"
```

While combining i want

```
"12 \U0001f973\U0001f973.xlsx"
```

I have tried
Test 1

```
string output = Regex.Replace(filename, @"[^\w\s\.\\[\]()|_-]+|[^\u0000-\u007F]+", "");
        "12 .xlsx" // but no luck
```

Test 2

```
string output = Regex.Replace(filename, @"[^-\w\s\.\\\[\]()|_\u0000-\u007F]+", "");
     prints "";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the "opposite" of your unicode range in order to be able to add it to your negated character class. Try:

```
[^\u0080-\uFFFF\w\s\.\\[\]()|_-]+
```

Comment: hmm this works as expected will test further and upvote the answer

Comment: Also i want to replace multiple backslash('\') with single slash
For eg:
 123\\\\123\\\\\U0001f973123\U0001f973\U0001f973\U0001f973123.txt
to 
output = 123\123\U0001f973123\U0001f973\U0001f973\U0001f973123.txt

ive tried Regex.replace(filename, @"[/\\] { 2 ,}", "\\"); 

but it prints

123\\123\\\U0001f973123\U0001f973\U0001f973\U0001f973123.txt

Comment: @BUlle7 `Regex.Replace(@"\\\\\\", @"[\\]{2,}", @"\")` works

Comment: works on c# online compiler dont knw whats wrong my real project its still showing double slash

Comment: @BUlle7 How are you inspecting the resulting string? Depending on your method a single backslash might be shown with an escaping backslash before it inserted by the debugger display.

Comment: [^\u0080-\uFFFF\w\s\.[\]()|_-]+ i had to remove \\ in above answer 
which solved my issue i think immediate windows shows multiple \\ while debuggin

Comment: i need to change my regex to allow unciodes text character and disallow some special characters
like below eg does the trick but i dont want to add special characters to that list
only disallowed characters like ( <>/ | * :  ) (only add this to the regex)

Regex.Replace("213123!@#$%^&*()_<>", @"[^\u0080-\uFFFF\w\s\.[\]()$#@|_-]+", "");